# Xamarin.Forms Android app restarts after external activity is launched

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

One of the features in my Xamarin.Forms Android app allows the user to choose a photo from the Gallery (it is the `IMediaPicker` custom control from XLabs that displays the native gallery activity, just like you do in any other regular Xamarin.Android app).

The problem is that sometimes the device gets low on memory (again, normal stuff) and when the image is chosen, the `MainActivity`from XF is restarted (as expected) and the app starts in the main page, instead of the page where the user previously was.

How do I handle such situation in Xamarin.Forms? E.g, continue from the Page the user was before opening the gallery activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try saving the state of your application by overriding the [OnSleep method](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/app-lifecycle/#Lifecycle_Methods).

There is one example of implementation in the [Xamarin Forms Samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Todo/PCL/Todo/App.cs). Particularly, check OnSleep and OnResume:

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("OnSleep saving ResumeAtTodoId = " + ResumeAtTodoId);
    // the app should keep updating this value, to
    // keep the "state" in case of a sleep/resume
    Properties ["ResumeAtTodoId"] = ResumeAtTodoId;
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("OnResume");
    if (Properties.ContainsKey ("ResumeAtTodoId")) {
        var rati = Properties ["ResumeAtTodoId"].ToString();

        Debug.WriteLine ("   rati="+rati);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (rati)) {
            Debug.WriteLine ("   rati = " + rati);
            ResumeAtTodoId = int.Parse (rati);

            if (ResumeAtTodoId >= 0) {
                var todoPage = new TodoItemPage ();
                todoPage.BindingContext = Database.GetItem (ResumeAtTodoId);
                MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync (
                    todoPage, false); // no animation
            }
        }
    }
}
```